# Sending inner text of <a></a> tags as a parameter to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, this, innerhtml

I would like to send the text between an  pair as a parameter to a javascript function.

Im trying this:

```
<a href="javascript: insertTag(this.innerHTML);">cats</a>
```

The function insertTag() is called, but the parameter sent looks to be "undefined" when I access it within the insertTag() function.

What am I doing wrong and how can I send what's between the  tags as a parameter for my "insertTag" function (eg. "cats" in the example shown above?

Assigning the  an id and then using GetElementById(id).innerhtml works, but I feel like there might be a simpler way without having to assign "ids" to each  pair that calls the function.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to how `onclick`, `onchange`, and any other `on` attributes work, the `href` attribute used with `javascript:` will not set `this` to the HTML element the attribute is defined on. So it will be set the global object `window`, which does not have an `innerHTML` property.

To make your use case work, do this:

```
<a href="javascript: null" onclick="insertTag(this.innerHTML);">cats</a>
```

Now the `href` attribute defines no specific action (`null` does nothing), but is still there to make the `a` element render as a hyperlink. The real action is now dealt with in the `onclick` attribute, where `this` will be what you expected.

#### A remark

Most will consider it better practice to define click handlers in separate JavaScript code, like this:

```
document.querySelector('#mylink').addEventListener("click", function () {
    insertTag(this.innerHTML);
});
```

And your element would be:

```
<a href="javascript: null" id="mylink">cats</a>
```

This has the advantage that the on-click handler code is parsed when the script loads, not when the user clicks. So any syntax errors would immediately be reported.

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you. And for the explanation. It works beautifully. :-) I will look into the "best practices" changes too. Again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are using JavaScript inline with your HTML and `this` is not being bound to hyperlink as you expect.

Instead, [separate your JavaScript from your HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) and set up your event handlers like this:

```js
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Don't use .innerHTML when there is no HTML
  // Use .textContent instead
  test(this.textContent);
});

function test(content){
  console.log(content);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">cats</a>
```

But, better still, don't use hyperlinks as triggers for JavaScript. Just about any visible (and some invisible) elements can be clicked on and trigger a `click` event. Hyperlinks are for navigation and people that rely on screen readers will have issues if hyperlinks are used for other purposes. Instead, another inline element, like a `span` should be used:

```js
document.querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Don't use .innerHTML when there is no HTML
  // Use .textContent instead
  test(this.textContent);
});

function test(content){
  console.log(content);
}
```

```html
<span>cats</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look into incorporating this strategy in the code.